# How to fake data based on the condition and weight

Tags: python, dataset, bigdata

I'm trying to fake data for the coffee shop. I've two features age and menu. Menu includes various type of drinks such as coffee [latte, espresso, mocca, etc], tea [milktea, lemontea], milk [freshmilk, matchamilk, etc]. What I'm trying to do is to fake menu based on the age like if the age is higher than 15, 80% of people who has the age higher than 15 will mostly order coffee randomly from the list of coffee [latte, espresso, mocca, etc], 20% will order milk and tea. Any idea on how to do this in the python?

Comment: How do you want behavior to change as age changes?

Comment: In general you could use a parameterized Dirichlet distribution to generate categorical distributions, where you shift the $\alpha$ vector depending on age.

Answer (score 0):

There are many Python packages to generate synthetic data. One example is [Faker](https://pypi.org/project/Faker/).